# Where do I get the source for microsoft.web.helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

My vs2010 has an issue installing the mvc3 and NuGet. It is on win7 the error is cannot create app dir.

But What I would like is to get the source for microsoft.web.helpers.dll. But I cannot seem to find the source nor the files to download outside of NuGet???

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781).

Comment: that seems to be only mvc 3 *not*  microsoft.web.helpers

Comment: @Joe: It's in the same download.

Comment: really then why use NuGet to get it??